# Detecting Memory and CPU consumption of a particluar app

Tags: java, android, memory, cpu-usage

I want to detect the **Memory** and **CPU** **consumption** of a **particular app** in **android** (programmatically), can any one help me with it. I have tried the TOP method, but i want an alternative for it.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you wan to trace your memory usage in your app then there is [ActivityManager.getMemoryInfo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.MemoryInfo.html) API.

Cpu usage can be traced using [CpuStatsCollector](http://source.android.com/reference/com/android/tradefed/device/CpuStatsCollector.html) API.

For more informative memory usage overview, outside your app, you can use `adb shell dumpsys meminfo <package_name|pid> [-d]` for more specific memory usage statistics. For example, there is the the command for `com.google.android.apps.maps` process:

`adb shell dumpsys meminfo com.google.android.apps.maps -d`

Which gives you a following output:

```
** MEMINFO in pid 18227 [com.google.android.apps.maps] **
               Pss  Private  Private  Swapped     Heap     Heap     Heap
             Total    Dirty    Clean    Dirty     Size    Alloc     Free
            ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------   ------
Native Heap    10468    10408        0        0    20480    14462     6017
Dalvik Heap    34340    33816        0        0    62436    53883     8553
Dalvik Other      972      972        0        0
    Stack     1144     1144        0        0
  Gfx dev    35300    35300        0        0
Other dev        5        0        4        0
 .so mmap     1943      504      188        0
 .apk mmap      598        0      136        0
 .ttf mmap      134        0       68        0
 .dex mmap     3908        0     3904        0
 .oat mmap     1344        0       56        0
 .art mmap     2037     1784       28        0
Other mmap       30        4        0        0
EGL mtrack    73072    73072        0        0
GL mtrack    51044    51044        0        0
  Unknown      185      184        0        0
    TOTAL   216524   208232     4384        0    82916    68345    14570
```

(output trimmed) More about it [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html#ViewingAllocations)

Tracing of memory usage on modern operating systems is very complex task. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-do-i-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android) for more info.

Comment: Can i use it through app that is programmatically

Comment: CpuStatsCollector API is not public API, Hence we cannot use this, please verify before posting an answer

Comment: @Amritesh meaning we can't use CpuStatsCollector?

Comment: @InsurgentPointerException API is not exposed to developer.. hence we cannot use.

Answer (score -1):

To get your processid:

```
int pid = android.os.Process.myPid();
```

To get CPU Usage :

```
public String getCPUUsage(int pid) {
   Process p;
   try {
   String[] cmd = {
      "sh",
      "-c",
      "top -m 1000 -d 1 -n 1 | grep \""+pid+"\" "};
   p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
   String line = reader.readLine();
   // line contains the process info
}
```

Comment: This code you can put in your app (you have to print the line in log), at certain places and or in a broadcast receiver, which you can trigger at certain instances and check the logs in the console.