# How to Get CPU usage programmatically (With the cores frequency)

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to get an approach of CPU usage (of all cores)

Currenlty i can't get the info of "/proc/stat" (since API 27)

so i think of getting the info with the frequency or similar:

Working with all the previous answers i get close to what i want, but not enough

**Main Func**

```
  private fun ReadCpu3():String{

        val sb = StringBuffer();
        sb.append("abi: ").append(Build.CPU_ABI).append("\n");

        if (File("/proc/cpuinfo").exists()) {
            try {
                //val br =  BufferedReader(FileReader(File("/proc/cpuinfo")));
                val file = File("/proc/cpuinfo")

                file.bufferedReader().forEachLine {
                    sb.append(it+"\n");
                }

            } catch (e: IOException) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

**My results**

```
    processor       : 0
    vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
    cpu family      : 6
    model           : 45
    model name      : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2660 0 @ 2.20GHz
    stepping        : 6
    microcode       : 1561
    cpu MHz         : 600.000
    cache size      : 20480 KB
    physical id     : 0
    siblings        : 16
    core id         : 0
    cpu cores       : 8
    apicid          : 0
    initial apicid  : 0
    fpu             : yes
    fpu_exception   : yes
    cpuid level     : 13
    wp              : yes
    flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm ida arat epb pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid xsaveopt
    bogomips        : 4399.93
    clflush size    : 64
    cache_alignment : 64
    address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
    power management:
```

So i get all the info of the CPU but not the actual load or usage. I do not know if with the current info i can manage to get a proximity of the cpu usage and how exactly.

Comment: Why tag with java when you want to ask about kotlin. And I think kotlin follows similar naming conventions: variable names should start camelCase. UpperCase is for class names. Also note: the purpose of vertical spacing (empty lines) is to group things. You dont just throw out empty lines here or there because you can. Imagine how it would feel if your code was written ... like you cared about it?!

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks for the advices, i corrected it :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find CPU load of any Android device programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46714396/how-to-find-cpu-load-of-any-android-device-programmatically)

Comment: @Divergence But i only want CPU load, and i in this awnser it returns a whole textview of info, can you give me an idea of what can i do in order to get just the CPU load using this code as base ?

Comment: @WhySoBizarreCode then please attach a sample of what it returns.

Comment: @Divergence I ReAsk the question, taking as a base all the info that you give me.

Comment: I've discovered a SO post that provides you with exactly what you need. See my answer.

Comment: @WhySoBizarreCode updated my answer again. The Android O and above security problem cannot be resolved; It's _intentional_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should see [this SO post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405403/android-cpu-cores-reported-in-proc-stat).
Basically, you want to use the `RandomAccessFile` class to parse the `/proc/stat` file.

**EDIT:** The above solution won't work for Android O and above. [See this link for more information](https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/6fdglt/apparent_android_o_proc_permissions_changes/). The Reddit user fornwall filed a report to Google about this and got:

> Status: Won't Fix (Intended Behavior) Thank you for filing this bug
>   report.
>
> The removal of /proc/stat was intentional. /proc/stat leaks side
>   channel information about applications which could allow one
>   application to infer the state of other applications on the device.
>   See
>   [https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~lmrs2/publications/interrupts_pets16.pdf](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~lmrs2/publications/interrupts_pets16.pdf%20for%20example.)
>   for example.

**EDIT2:** I've prepared an example (not using CpuStasCollector)

```java
package com.k3.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static int sLastCpuCoreCount = -1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.txtv);
        textView.setText("");
        for (int i = 0; i < calcCpuCoreCount(); i++) {
            textView.append(takeCurrentCpuFreq(i) +"\n");
        }
    }

    private static int readIntegerFile(String filePath) {

        try {
            final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(filePath)), 1000);
            final String line = reader.readLine();
            reader.close();

            return Integer.parseInt(line);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    private static int takeCurrentCpuFreq(int coreIndex) {
        return readIntegerFile("/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu" + coreIndex + "/cpufreq/scaling_cur_freq");
    }

    public static int calcCpuCoreCount() {

        if (sLastCpuCoreCount >= 1) {
            // キャッシュさせる
            return sLastCpuCoreCount;
        }

        try {
            // Get directory containing CPU info
            final File dir = new File("/sys/devices/system/cpu/");
            // Filter to only list the devices we care about
            final File[] files = dir.listFiles(new FileFilter() {

                public boolean accept(File pathname) {
                    //Check if filename is "cpu", followed by a single digit number
                    if (Pattern.matches("cpu[0-9]", pathname.getName())) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

            // Return the number of cores (virtual CPU devices)
            sLastCpuCoreCount = files.length;

        } catch(Exception e) {
            sLastCpuCoreCount = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        }

        return sLastCpuCoreCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can not use /proc/stat file in andorid API27 or higer for security reasons. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782894/error-reading-cpu-usage-proc-stat-permission-denied

Comment: Well, that's great. I'll keep digging.

Comment: However there are apps that shows the cpu usage, so i think that they are using frequency or another way in order to achieve that.

Comment: Do they run Android O+?

Comment: Because if they don't, that could be the reason they run

Comment: Yes they run in andorid o+

Comment: Hmm, do you know if CpuStatsCollector works on android O+? If you find that it does let me know and check this SO Post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31564610/detecting-memory-and-cpu-consumption-of-a-particluar-app

Comment: https://github.com/takke/cpustats he for example get the cpu usage with the frequency but i don't know how, because the same function it always returns me the same number that current frequency like -1000 both so it doesn't make any sense

Comment: Found this: https://github.com/kamgurgul/cpu-info. Its an app to track CPU/RAM usage and other Hardware properties. I'm currently finding the method to retrieve it.

Comment: i would like to try with CpuStatsCollector but i dont really get how it works, i mean i have to add some library ?

Comment: All of the other CPU info apps I see targeting Android O+ use libraries, and I don't really see any other way...

Comment: but can you give me an example of how to use CpuStatCollector ? and so i can mark your awnser like the correct too.

Comment: @WhySoBizarreCode I've made my own example off of github.com/kamgurgul/cpu-info as you mentioned. Please check the latest edit.

Comment: Can you not just check `/sys/devices/system/cpu/present` to get the number of cores? For example, `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/present` will give something like `0-3`. Or maybe `possible`?

Comment: The OP wants the CPU usage, not the number of cores.